# VLC outputs no video, only audio

Tags: debugging, vlc, movie

I am trying to install VLC from source so as to utilize the raspberry pi's hardware (question is software only, hence why I am asking here) as per [these instructions](http://intensecode.blogspot.ca/2013/10/tutorial-vlc-with-hardware-acceleration.html?showComment=1382516495999#c2670305538844880670). I have managed to install it, however, I can't see any video, only hear audio. There are two ways I can launch a video, if I launch it without hardware usage, via `vlc filename`, I get the below error, I see no window launched, but I hear audio. If I launch it with hardware usage, via `vlc --vout omxil_vout filename`, I still get the same error, but I do see a window launched, it displays the movie name, and I hear the audio, however, the window is completely black.

**Error** (when run as verbose. Also, note that the X11 error has to do with the fact that I am running over putty right now, but I get the same error otherwise):

```
VLC media player 2.2.0-git Weatherwax (revision 2.1.0-git-1098-g5e5a9ad)
[0xab89e8] main libvlc warning: cannot read /home/raspi/downloads/vlc/src/.libs/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat (No such file or directory)
[0xb3cb18] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xab89e8] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0xb3caf0] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0xb3caf0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xab89e8] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0xab89e8] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0xb3ded0] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.0-git Weatherwax
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> [matroska,webm @ 0xb5f2a500] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[matroska,webm @ 0xb5f17860] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[0xb3c180] main video output error: video output creation failed
[0xb5f347b0] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[0xb5f347b0] main decoder warning: can't get output picture
[0xb5f347b0] avcodec decoder warning: disabling direct rendering
[0xb36b48] main audio output warning: playback too late (60415): up-sampling
[0xb36b48] main audio output warning: playback too late (60226): up-sampling
[0xb36b48] main audio output warning: timing screwed (drift: 121945 us): stopping resampling
[0xb36b48] main audio output warning: playback too late (122085): up-sampling
^C[0xb3ded0] [cli] lua interface error: Error loading script /home/raspi/downloads/vlc/share/lua/intf/cli.luac: lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279: Interrupted.
```

I know the problem has something to do with these two lines:

```
[0xb3c180] main video output error: video output creation failed
[0xb5f347b0] main decoder error: failed to create video output
```

but they don't give me enough information to begin troubleshooting. Could someone please help me diagnose this problem.

Comment: IMHO this question should be moved to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ (From What topics can I ask about here?: "Software that runs on the Raspberry Pi")

Comment: It's a tough call, I won't argue either way.

Comment: And even if it is off-topic, there is no need to downvote this question. The question is well-writen and contains as much information as you can offer.